# How to make this code more useful (preventing special characters in textarea)

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am using this code and working fine but the problem with this code is, its not optimized and for an example if i want to add few more characters then i will end-up having ifs....

```
if (keychar == "#" || keychar == "!" || keychar == "$" ..........)
```

is there a way to optimized this code? meaning less ifs (if i need to add more special characters to prevent)

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function check(e) {
            var keynum
            var keychar
            var numcheck
            // For Internet Explorer
            if (window.event) {
                keynum = e.keyCode
            }
            // For Netscape/Firefox/Opera
            else if (e.which) {
                keynum = e.which
            }
            keychar = String.fromCharCode(keynum)
            //List of special characters you want to restrict
            if (keychar == "'" || keychar == "a") {

                return false;
            }
            else {
                return true;
            }
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Just to make sure; you do know you still need to check on the server too, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
switch(keychar) {
    case "#":
    case "!":
    case "$":
       ...
    default:
       ...
}
```

OR

```
if( keychar.match(/[#!$]/))
```

Answer (score 1):

Define the list of characters to restrict in a string, and search for the key entered using [**`indexOf`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).

```
keychar = String.fromCharCode(keynum);
return "'a#!$".indexOf(keychar) == -1;
```

Comment: do you know the list of special character list?

Comment: Depends on your business needs.  I don't know your application requirements.

Answer (score 0):

```
function check(e) {
    var event = e || window.event;
    var keychar = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
    switch(keychar) {
        case 'a':
        case 'b':
        case 'c':
        /*
         * case 'd':
         * case 'e':
         * ...
         */
            return false;
        default:
            return true;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

how to restrict special characters in textbox using jquery

```
 $("#txtUploadFrequency").keypress(function (e) {
    if (String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode).match(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/g)) return false;
});`enter code here`
```